# Order of code execute in java

Tags: java, int, operators, double

I was running the following code

```
int x=4;
int y=3;
double z=1.5;
z=++x/y*(x-- +2);
int t=(++x/y);
    System.out.println(z); //7
```

wondering how does it produce 7 when

1. (x-- +2) =6
2. ++x/y=1.6666

   3=6*1.6666=10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
z=++x/y*(x-- +2);
```

is evaluated as:

```
z = ++x / y * (x-- + 2);  // Substitute value of ++x, y and x--
  = 5 / 3 * (5 + 2);      // After this point, x will be 4. Evaluate parenthesized expr
  = 5 / 3 * 7   // Now, left-to-right evaluation follows
  = 1 * 7       // 5 / 3 due to integer division will give you 1, and not 1.66
```

and:

```
t = ++x / y;   // x is 4 here
  = 5 / 3
  = 1
```

Comment: (++x / y) how this get executed first, as it is not in the round brackets.. () are supposed to be evaluted first

Comment: @user1765876 Even though `(x-- + 2)` part will be evaluated first, that will not make any difference to the result. As the value for `++x` and `x--` will be substituted before evaluation.

Comment: @user1765876 Removed the parenthesis. Now it should be clear.

Comment: ++ or -- when comes before (leftside), it is incremented or decremented and then the immediate expression is evaluated. ++ or -- when comes after(right side) the variable, the immediate expression is evaluated first and then the new value will be assigned to the variable.

Comment: @sivatumma so you have an expression with  ++ and (SUB_EXPRESSION) which will be executed first?

Comment: @user1765876 The expression in the parenthesis will be evaluated first. But before evaluation, the value for all the variable are substituted. So, for `y / x++ * (x-- + 1)`, value of `x--` will be evalated after the value of `x++`. And then `(x-- + 1)` will be evaluated as an expression before `y / x++`.

Comment: In my experience, ++ or -- (unary operators) are only applied to individual variables but not to an expression. What I was saying was the behavior of that `unary operator`.. and how it happens..

Answer (score 1):

The code is evaluated as:

```
z=((++x)/y)*(x-- +2);
```

x and y are both int, so the calculation results of each step will be cast into int type. Which means `5/3=1`.

In the end, the result is assigned to a double variable, so `7` will be cast to `7.0`.

Modify the code to:

```
z=1.0 * ((++x)/y)*(x-- +2);
```

You'll get a decimal result.